# Downloading private patches from Github

Tags: git, curl, github

When a PR is created in the private repos of my organization, I receive emails from Github with links such as `http://github.com/<my org>/<project>/<PR #>.patch`.  I would like to download such links with curl; as-is, I get a 404, and I can't seem to find the right incantation with `-H "Authorization: <oauth token>"` to make it work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use Github API to do this, get the pull request with [this API](https://developer.github.com/v3/pulls/#get-a-single-pull-request) :

```
GET /repos/:owner/:repo/pulls/:number
```

You can use a [personal access token](https://github.com/settings/tokens) with `repos` scope to get the result for a private repo with the authorization header : `-H 'Authorization: token YOUR_TOKEN'`

Use [commits comparison and pull request](https://developer.github.com/v3/media/#commits-commit-comparison-and-pull-requests) media types :

- patch : `application/vnd.github.VERSION.patch`
- diff : `application/vnd.github.VERSION.diff`

The curl requests are :

- request patch for PR #18 :

  ```
  curl -H 'Authorization: token YOUR_TOKEN' \
       -H 'Accept: application/vnd.github.VERSION.patch' \
       https://api.github.com/repos/<my org>/<project>/pulls/18
  ```
- request diff for PR #18

  ```
  curl -H 'Authorization: token YOUR_TOKEN' \
       -H 'Accept: application/vnd.github.VERSION.diff' \
       https://api.github.com/repos/<my org>/<project>/pulls/18
  ```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer, that works very nicely!

Comment: Thank you soooo much it's exactly what i wanted